# Can this be done in an ElasticSearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can this be done in an ElasticSearch query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users_contacts.value)
FROM users
INNER JOIN users_contacts ON users_contacts.user_id = users.id
WHERE users_contacts.type = "email"
```

Without `users_contacts.type = "email"` condition, I can use ValueCount aggregation.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Its not as difficult as it seems.

Comment: I can't compose equal elastic query, not quite clear how do this. Can you please write some example?

Comment: See my edited answer :)

Comment: Please let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use top_hits aggregation as shown in documentation link bellow

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

**EDIT**

I try to do my best to show how to do this. First of all I hope, you have your contacts saved in its own documents

**1. Create mapping**

```
{
    "dynamic": true,
    "_all": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "properties":{
        "user_id" : {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "contact_type" : {
            "type":"string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Insert documents**

use this as template to create multiple documents (change text, number and date)

```
    {
        "user_id": 5,
        "contact_type": "email"
    }
```

**3. Query itself**

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "contact_type":{
                "value":"email"
            } 
        }
     },
    "aggs": {
        "contact-counts": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user_id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**4.See the result**

search for **aggregations** key and **contact-counts** within it

it should look something like this

```
"aggregations": {
    "contact-counts": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": 4,                       // user_id
                "doc_count": 1                 // document count
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I hope it helps! :)

**EDIT**

In the end you dont need top_hits aggregation, just plain aggregation itself :)